# Finding even numbers using for loop in C language

Tags: c

Can someone  please show or tell how to fix my code so that it can  determine even numbers. Am new to for loops and C.

EDIT: please paste code here instead of image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please paste the code here, do not post pictures of code and explain what did you try.

Comment: We cannot fix your code because it makes no sense. Describe the requirements and post your code here, not somewhere else.

Comment: read up on modulo operator %

Comment: Or just AND with `1`. Any number AND `1` that results in `1` (true) is odd, If the result is `0`, the number is even. No division involved (though a good compiler will optimize that for you)

Comment: [Short Example using both AND and modulo](https://godbolt.org/z/zcqo7ac3h) It also shows the use of the *ternary* which reduces the entire program evaluating even/odd for 0-100 to 8-lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just posted the code along with your question but man I could hardly understand your code so I'll make some silly assumptions about what you were trying to do.

1)

```c
printf("even number is %d",);
```

Firstly I am doubly sure that this did not compile because of the hanging comma, number two removing the comma will either print rubbish or cause the entire program to crash because that `%d` is supposed to be accompanied by an integer argument for example:

```c
printf("even number is %d", a);
```

It has to do with the way C handles variadic arguments.

2)
Instead of handling the input gotten from `scanf` you went on to check if `i` is an even number which makes no sense, of course the if statement there checks if it is an even number but then there's no need for asking for input.

3)
I suggest changing your code to this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, i = 0; //remove one of the variables
    printf("Enter 10 positive values\n");
    while (i < 10)
    {
        printf("Enter a number:");
        if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1)    //ask for input first and check if scanf failed
        {
            printf("An error occured\n"); /*now scanf will push back the string or whatever it read back in the stdin stream
                                            if it encounters a non integer value ('d' for example) and return 0 if this happens ther's something you can do about that but I'm not going to bother going into that
                                            now such an error can happen because of other reasons do this research on your own*/
            return 1;
        }
        if (a < 0)       //check if a is positive
        {
            printf("%d is not positive please enter an even number\n", a); //print an error message if a is not positive
            continue;                                                      //go back to the beginning of the loop
        }
        else
        {
            if ((a % 2) == 0)
            {
                printf("%d is an even number\n", a);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d is not an even number\n", a);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("Done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: okay let me change that